# Why does this code only writes the variable in the first row of the table?

Tags: excel, vba

Why does this code only writes the variable "Duracao" (duration) in the row 11th and not in the 12th and 13th? You can see the image of the excel table here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6LJw.png

Basically, I have for each helicopter several jobs with beginning and finish dates and I want to get the duration (in days) of each job.

```
 Sub EscalaDinâmicaHTA()

Dim NumHelis As Integer
Dim DataInicio As Date
Dim DataFim As Date
Dim ContData As Double
Dim LinHeliInicial As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer

NumHelis = Worksheets(1).Range("B8").Value
LinHeliInicial = 11
LinTotal = LinHeliInicial + NumHelis - 1

i = 2
j = 3
k = 4


Do While LinHeliInicial <= LinTotal
Do While i < 26 And j < 27 And k < 28

DataInicio = Worksheets(1).Cells(LinHeliInicial, i).Value
ContData = DateValue(DataInicio)
ContData = Val(ContData)

DataFim = Worksheets(1).Cells(LinHeliInicial, j).Value
DataFim = DateValue(DataFim)

Duracao = DataFim - DateValue(DataInicio)
Worksheets(1).Cells(LinHeliInicial, k).Value = Duracao + 1
Duracao = ContData + Duracao
Duracao = Val(Duracao)

ContData = ContData - 43072        
Duracao = Duracao - 43072

k = k + 3
j = j + 3
i = i + 3

Loop

Do While ContData <= Duracao
Cells(LinHeliInicial, ContData).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
ContData = ContData + 1
Loop



LinHeliInicial = LinHeliInicial + 1
Loop



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   i = 2
>   j = 3
>   k = 4
>   Do While LinHeliInicial <= LinTotal
>   Do While i < 26 And j < 27 And k < 28
> ```

You need to re-initialize `i, j, k` in every iteration on `LinHeliInicial`. Switch the order of the above lines into this:

```
  Do While LinHeliInicial <= LinTotal
    i = 2
    j = 3
    k = 4
    Do While i < 26 And j < 27 And k < 28
```

Comment: I already did it but it doesn't work. It appears me an error: "Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error" and it prevents the first loop from going to the 2nd step.

Comment: @MiguelLeal This solves the current issue of writing only the first line. You must have other issues in your data, such as assuming some cells are `Dates` while they are not valid dates. Could be something else as well.